# how can I update a field with the count on other field while using inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a temp table and i have a field called schedulesTotal in it. I want to update it with a count based on a select. but i am not sure if my logic is correct.

this is my code

```
UPDATE    [#tempMike]
SET              schedulesTotal = total
        (
        SELECT    ta.accountid,
            COUNT(New_NextCallDueDate) as total FROM [#tempMike] AS ta
            INNER JOIN PhoneCall AS p WITH (nolock) ON ta.accountid = p.regardingobjectid 
        group by ta.accountid
        )
```

if I run the select part by itself i get 1 account numer along with the total value correctly I now just want to update the temp table with the total value that is returned by the select statment

This is the error that I currently get

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE   A
SET   schedulesTotal = total
FROM  [#tempMike] A
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT    ta.accountid,
            COUNT(New_NextCallDueDate) as total FROM [#tempMike] AS ta
            INNER JOIN PhoneCall AS p WITH (nolock) 
            ON ta.accountid = p.regardingobjectid 
            group by ta.accountid
        ) B ON A.accountid = B.accountid
```

Edit:

`UPDATE A` is using alias `'A'`, that we gave to temptable in from clause - `[#tempMike] A`, to update temp table. You can also use `UPDATE [#tempMike]`

Comment: Nice. yes this did it :)   Thank you very much :) Can you please explain what is Update A is doing?

Comment: Thank you :) Thank makes sence :)

Answer (score 0):

Your UPDATE is wrong-formed, try to fix using this structure:

```
update TABLE
SET COLUMN = ( select count(*) from ANOTHER_TABLE where COLUMN1 = TABLE.COLUMN1)
;
```

Note COLUMN is assigned only one value (In this case COUNT(*) which itself is a GROUP function and you don´t need to group by ).

HTH